# HTML - Sizing divs

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with the following div's.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id=left></div>
    <div id=right></div>
</div>
```

As the body of the page is background color blue and assume
div left and div right are white.
when the content of say right div reaches the 
height of div main, div main does not expand
so it looks odd.

How do I get div main expand when div right expands past it?

Hope this is not confusing.

Malcolm

Comment: You should probably rename your question: "CSS- Clearing Floats"

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming "left" and "right" means you are floating them left and right with your CSS.

If so, you need to [clear them](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). Make your HTML look like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id=left></div>
    <div id=right></div>
    <br style='clear: both;'>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a link explaining what it is meant to do. If that is not working then you need to paste your CSS code.

Comment: why do you use BR tag? why not just DIV? even your link that you've posted is using DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can (need to) use reset css file to handle these kind of css issues. You can see a detailed information about Yahoo's reset css file [from here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) 
 Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

Are your 'left' and 'right' divs floated? By default, your 'main' div won't expand around floated elements it contains. You can fix this by adding `overflow: auto` to `div#main` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#equal      {
        overflow: hidden;
        }

#left, #right{
        padding-bottom: 5000px;
        margin-bottom: -5000px;
        width: 150px;
        }

#left       {
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
        }

#right      {
        float: right;
        background-color: green;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="equal">
<div id="left">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
<div id="right">blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give overflow: hidden property to #main's CSS. Also you should **always** quote the attribute values. (You did not when assigning id's to the #left and #right)